# Animation not rendering (viewport still fine) & Random per island changes color on every frame

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, instances, random

[image: rendered issue]Somehow my animation is not rendering, it just render every frame I tell it to but no change in actual object movement. The playback in viewport is running fine.

Also, I used random per island to assign random color to each sphere, but when I render on random frames their color kept changing randomly, how can I make the color stick to each sphere throughout the entire timeline?

[Link to my .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FJFigUFTBZ-EikFhvUKJQnnGCULdNia/view?usp=sharing)

Edit: I solved the not rendering animation problem with Realize Instances node in geomatry node editor. But the colors are still changing every frame.

[image: my shader node setup]

Comment: pls provide blend file because we have no idea what you did except for this one shader node. I just can assume that you generate new islands somehow....

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added a link to my blend file

Comment: uhm....there is no color change when i start your file...maybe you wanna download 4.0alpha version? or...what version r u using?

Comment: @Chris The screenshot says it's version 3.6.0

Comment: using 3.6 right now, could you try rendering a few frames? The issue I'm facing is not in viewport but in rendered images (especially around the 45-65th frames, when the spheres begin to separate). Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Chris also I just tried 4.0 alpha, the issue remains

Comment: well...i see no color change here....[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Dbu.gif so maybe the windows version has a problem...i am working on a macbook

Comment: @Chris Of course it won't exhibit any change in your gif, the Random per island node is Cycles only, If you want to replicate the issue, you can try rendering in Cycles

Comment: ah ok...sorry, will take a look later

Answer (score 0):

hopefully you want a solution, and not(!) that the random per island works somehow...

so here is my solution proposal:

by using this GN setup:

[image]

you create your "own" randomized per island attribute and you can use that in your shader node tree:

[image]

result (this time cycles rendering ;). ):

[image]